# Getting error with sql server database in Yii framework

Tags: php, yii

I am switching to sql server from mysql database. The new database is same as previous database. But in create user action i am getting this type of error.

> ```
> include( .php) [<a href='function.include'>function.include</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory
> ```

Can anyone suggest what I can do to resolve this?

The problem is showing on this line

```
$profile->attributes = $_POST['YumProfile'];
```

I have check from code that all objects are working and i am getting of `$_POST['YumProfile']` value properly.

Actually this logic is working properly with a other `user` table and value is inserting, but when I try to insert the data with a form into `profile` table then it shows this type of error. Everything is looking ok from the input but I can't understand why

```
 $profile->attributes = $_POST['YumProfile'];
```

this line gives error even `profile->validate()` and `profile->save()` also gives this error while `$profile->attributes` and `$_POST['YumProfile']` are working properly and filled with proper values.

Comment: Don't post just the line it says the error is in, post the entire call stack (backtrace) if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like something is wrong in your model's validation rules. Check if everything in place there, probably you miss something. Here is [an api docs](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CModel#rules-detail)